# Can't pass value as function in React Navite Element Button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to display model with the key value from array, but I can't do it, and I don't understand the problem.

this is react native in Expo and I have used react native elements

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { ScrollView, Text, Linking, View, Modal } from "react-native";
import { Card, Button } from "react-native-elements";
import PriceDetail from "./PriceDetail";

const images = [
  {
    key: 1,
    name: "Nathan Anderson",
    image: require("../images/1.jpg"),
    url: "https://unsplash.com/photos/C9t94JC4_L8"
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    name: "Jamison McAndie",
    image: require("../images/2.jpg"),
    url: "https://unsplash.com/photos/waZEHLRP98s"
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    name: "Alberto Restifo",
    image: require("../images/3.jpg"),
    url: "https://unsplash.com/photos/cFplR9ZGnAk"
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    name: "John Towner",
    image: require("../images/4.jpg"),
    url: "https://unsplash.com/photos/89PFnHKg8HE"
  }
];

class Home extends Component {

  state = {
    selectedItem : null,
    mvisible : false
  }

  modalClosedHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      mvisible: false,
      selectedItem: null
    });
  };

  productSelectedHandler = key => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        selectedItem: prevState.images.find(image => {
          return image.key === key;
        })
      };
    });
    console.log(selectedItem);
  };

  showModal = (key) => {
    this.setState({
        mvisible: true,
        selectedItem: key
      });
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Modal 
        visible={this.state.mvisible}
        onRequestClose={this.modalClosedHandler}>
        <View style={{flex : 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Hello this is modal{this.state.selectedItem}</Text>
        <Button title="Close" onPress={this.modalClosedHandler}/>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
        {images.map(({ name, image, url, key }) => (
          <Card title={`Product ${key}`} image={image} key={key}>
            <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
              Photo by {name}.
            </Text>
            <Button
              backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
              title="VIEW NOW"
              onPress={(key)=>this.showModal(key)}
            />
          </Card>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    );    
  }
}

export default Home;
```

I am new to react native.

Comment: What's the error? What happen?

Comment: The text limitations (that you probably faced) so that whole question isn't code are there so that you would add actual useful content, not "please check", "kindly help" and copy the same text twice into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont get key in the first parameter of button's onPress.

This is wrong:

```
<Button
          backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
          title="VIEW NOW"
          onPress={(key)=>this.showModal(key)}            
/>
```

You already have a key at higher level, so you should use this code:

```
<Button
          backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
          title="VIEW NOW"
          onPress={()=>this.showModal(key)}            
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure to understand well but if you have a problem while calling this.showModal is because you have an extra "key".

Replace

```
<Button
backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
title="VIEW NOW"
onPress={(key)=>this.showModal(key)}
/>
```

By

```
<Button
backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
title="VIEW NOW"
onPress={()=>this.showModal(key)}
/>
```